# Springboot wont redirect to forums on nginx

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a forum installed on the Nginx webserver and I have springboot running on the same server but im using nginx as a proxy so it works great, the issue is i have the forums installed on the nginx website folder named forums, and i added /forums/ to spring boot security but when i go to url/forums/ i get a spring security blocking me from the page?

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/rest", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/css/**", "/assets/**", "/login", "/register", "/font/**", "/fonts/**", "/sitemap.xml", "/hiscores", "/rest/players/get/**", "/rest/players/update/**",
                        "/rest/players/login/**", "/rest/**", "/pp/api/success", "/pay", "/pay/success", "/pay/cancel", "/classes", "/master/**", "/vendor/**", "/videos/**", "/img/**", "/forums/**", "/forums", "/download/", "/rest/version/", "/rest/changelog/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/dashboard/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
```

it should be allowing me to go to /forums/ of the url

EDIT:

```
Path    /forums
Error   Not Found
Status  404
Message No message available
```

Forums controller

```
@RestController
public class ForumsController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/forums/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showDashboard(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/forums");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something is catching your exception. Or your error is not comming from an exception. However, you need an error message to solve your problem.

Comment: ive edited the page, it shows /forums is not found, 404

Comment: That's what I had in mind. I wasn't sure, because your question was not that clear about how you deploy your forum.

Comment: You can't deploy two applications on the same root context, moreover you can't use Spring Security to secure a different application.

Comment: it is not a different application, its a php forums that is not a spring application, it is simply a directory in the nginx root folder

Comment: Yes, but it is not in the Spring Boot application. You can't protected any other appkication or folder outside of the Spring application.

Comment: i dont want it to be protected, i just want springboot to allow anyone to the /forums i dont want it to be protected my spring security at all